# Freeform Saves Email but Doesn't send

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, email

Freeform 5.0.3
EE 3.3.3

I've put my freeform form into a blank template with nothing else except the form and am still unable to receive any messages. When I test the form all entries are saved and viewable in the freeform CP. The form is redirecting correctly after submission.

I've looked at the [troubleshooting guide](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/troubleshooting/) and there are no error logs after form submission. I am able to recieve email using the communicate option in EE.

This is my form:

```
        {exp:freeform:form
            form_id="2"
            required="name|email"
            return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}"
            notify_admin="yes"
            admin_notify="myemail@domain.com"
            admin_notification_template="send-reel"
            recipient_template="send-reel"
            notify_user="yes"
            user_email_field="reciever_email"
        }


           <input type="hidden" name="reel_entry_ids" value="" />

          <fieldset>
            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Email Reel</legend>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="sender_email">Your Email</label>  
                  <input id="textinput" name="sender_email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control input-md">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="sender_name">Your Name</label>  
                  <input id="textinput" name="sender_name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control input-md">
                </div>  
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-6 -->

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="reciever_email">Receiver Email</label>  
                  <input id="textinput" name="receiver_email" type="email" placeholder="Receiver Email" class="form-control input-md">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="receiver_name">Receiver Name</label>  
                  <input id="textinput" name="receiver_name" type="text" placeholder="Receiver Name" class="form-control input-md">
                </div>  
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-6 -->

            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="subject">subject</label>  
                  <input id="textinput" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="subject" class="form-control input-md">
                </div>  
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 -->

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label sr-only" for="message">Message</label>
                  <div class="">                     
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
          </fieldset>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button id="singlebutton"  type="submit" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        {/exp:freeform:form}
        {!--end send reel form--}
```

**************** UPDATE *******************

I changed the form to one of the example forms from the docs which you can see below. The email module is installed and I can **send/recieve email using communicate** - reciving almost instantaneously. Entries are getting saved to the database but no email is being sent. Have checked spam folders and triple checked email addresses.

```
{exp:freeform:form
    form_id="2"
    return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}"
}
    <dl>
    {freeform:all_form_fields}
        <dt><label>{freeform:field_label}</label></dt>
        <dd>{freeform:field_output}</dd>
    {/freeform:all_form_fields}
    </dl>
    {if freeform:captcha}
        <p>Please enter the word you see in the image below:</p>
        <p>
            {freeform:captcha}
            <input type="text" name="captcha" />
        </p>
    {/if}
    <p>{freeform:submit}</p>
{if freeform:no_results}
    <p>
        Specified form was not found. Please make sure you have specified the
        correct short name of the form in the <b>form_name</b> parameter.
    </p>
{/if}
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Here is a screenshot of the form settings in the CP:

[image]

**************** UPDATE 2 *******************

Changed development server from my server to a subdomain of the live site on Nexcess and nothing has changed. Can still receive email via communicate but cannot receive any from the freeform form.

**************** UPDATE 3 *******************

Requested screenshot of notifications

[image]

Comment: Try using a different email address than your logged in super admin email.

Comment: @JimWyse Just tried that and no change. Also double checked spam folder.

Comment: is the email module installed?

Comment: No it wasn't.. wow, just noticed that most modules are not installed by default.

Comment: Installed email module, but still no change.

Comment: Updated post with more info and a settings screenshot

Comment: this is my tag on 3.3.3 with freeform 5.03 and it works
{exp:freeform:form form_id="1" name="contact-form" return="contact/bedankt" notify_admin="yes" admin_notification_template="contact" admin_notify="dijkstra@burodmg.nl" form:data-abide="true" form:novalidate="true"}

Comment: Thanks @JelleDijkstra still no go for me.

Comment: Is your admin_notify address (myemail@domain.com) the same as the address the notification is sent from? Many services including Gmail bounce self addresses emails that have a non-Google mail server origin.

Comment: One other thing i thought of: did you try with the other outgoing email settings? php mail/sendmail/smtp? /admin.php?/cp/settings/email

Comment: Added UPDATE 2 to post.  Have tried all options for sending.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your "send-reel" notification settings?

Comment: @DerekHogue Have updated with screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed this over a support ticket, and the issue was that `recipient_template="send-reel"` was being used instead of `user_notification_template="send-reel"`, and that the Outgoing Email EE setting was empty as it was being overridden by a blank in master config.

Comment: Thank you for your help on what in the end is clearly user error.